# Deleting Multiple Files Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, file

I'm new to programming Android, and I want to delete Files on the sd-card. This is my current (working) code...

```
File appvc = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath(), "ApplifierVideoCache");

if (appvc.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = appvc.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                new File(appvc, children[i]).delete();
            }
}
```

Now I want to delete multiple files, but dont want to mention each file with that big block. Am I able to combine all files in one variable? Thanks ;)

Comment: You could make an array of files and run your deletion code on every object in that array. Is that what you want?

Comment: `File` has `listFiles()`, which returns a `File[]` directly, no need to create your file objects... And your code won't work with deep removals. AND you do not check for the return code of `.delete()`!

Comment: @thegrinner, yes, that was what I wanted. But at that time, I was a noob and didn't know how ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility would be using the Apache commons-io library and calling

```
if (file.isDirectory())
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(File directory);
else {
    if(!file.delete())
        throw new IOException("Failed to delete " + file);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a recursive method:

```
/*
 * NOTE: coded so as to work around File's misbehaviour with regards to .delete(),
 * which does not throw an exception if it fails -- or why you should use Java 7's Files
 */

public void doDelete(final File base)
    throws IOException
{
    if (base.isDirectory()) {
        for (final File entry: base.listFiles())
            doDelete(entry);
        return;
    }

    if (!file.delete())
        throw new IOException ("Failed to delete " + file + '!');
}
```

Comment: Like this answer most because of the recursion, method is short, too :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a method out of this chunk of code, pass file name and call it whenever you like:

```
public void DeleteFile(String fileName) {
File appvc = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath(), fileName);

if (appvc.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = appvc.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                new File(appvc, children[i]).delete();
            }
}
}
```

Comment: It cannot resolve symbol "fileName"... Should I post the whole code?

Comment: read the first line - `fileName` is a string you should pass to  this function: `DeleteFile("whatever");`

Comment: You have some main activity in your program? Make this chunk of code it's method (you know about class methods and properties, aren't you?). Then, from another method, call it with string `DeleteFile("your_file_name");`

Comment: oh... :-) ... Yeah, just the wrong place I've put it...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
File dir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"ApplifierVideoCache");
```

Then call

```
deletedir(dir);

public void deletedir(File dir) {
File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
if (listFile != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
   listFile[i].delete();    
}  
}    
}
```

or if your folder as sub folders then

```
public void walkdir(File dir) {

File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

if (listFile != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) 
{
    if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) 
    {
       walkdir(listFile[i]);
    } else 
      {
       listFile[i].delete();    
      }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For kotlin**

Create a array of path list

```
    val paths: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    paths.add("Yor path")
    paths.add("Yor path")
    .
    .
```

delete file for each path

```
   try{
        paths.forEach{
             val file = File(it)
             if(file.exists(){
                  file.delete()
                }
         }
   }catch(e:IOException){

   }
```